# discord.js if else math.random not working as intended

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Basically I'm trying to use Math.random to make a discord bot answer a question with a 50/50 probability on each answer, but whenever i send the message on discord the bot won't answer.

My code currently looks like this:

```
const fiveo = Math.random();

switch(args[0]){
        case 'yesno':
            fiveo
            if(fiveo > 0.5){
                msg.channel.send('yes');
            }else{
                msg.channel.send('no');
            }
        break;   
    }
```

Any ideas how I can get this to work properly?

Comment: why do you have fiveo between case and if?

Comment: When I was using Math.round(Math.random()) to get 1 or 0, I didn't get an answer from the bot, so I thought it was due to fiveo not being called, which led me to inserting fiveo there to generate 1 or 0, which in the end didn't work as it was generating 1 all the time.